# Получение HANDLE любого изображения. WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть ли обобщенный способ для получения HANDLE изображения любого формата? Я знаю, что можно получать bitmap, например функцией LoadImage, просто имея .bmp файл, а что если я не хочу ограничивать себя этим типом файла, существуют ли инструменты для подгрузки в HANDLE jpeg, gif, png форматов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существуют, [их сначала перегоняют в bmp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5511849/5533854), а потом получают HANDLE.

И правильно писать на HANDLE, а HBITMAP

GDI - низкоуровневая библиотека, она работает только с сырыми пикселями.